# 2D Array loop behaving strangely (FCC)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm doing a learning exercise and am trying to understand the following code. I thought I had a handle on arrays and loops, but this one has got me very confused.

The below code:

```
  function zeroArray(m, n) 
  {  
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) 
  {    
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) 
    {      
      row.push(0);
    }    
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;

 }

 let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
 console.log(matrix);
```

Returns

```
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

However I would have expected it to return

```
[ [ 0, 0, ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Given that in each i loop, we are pushing (0) to row[] twice, before pushing row[] into newArray.

This isn't happening though, and in my VSCode debugger it looks as though in each i loop, every existing index of newArray is being updated with the latest version of the row[] array.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Start outer loop with `i = 1` upto `i <= m`, so the loop count will be `m`

```
for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
```

**2)** You should create a new `row` every time the inner loop start and push `row` into `newArray` after the inner loop ends

**3)** Set inner loop condition as `j < n * i`

```
  for (let j = 0; j < n * i; j++) {
```

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  // const row = []   // (-)
  for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    const row = []; // (+)
    for (let j = 0; j < n * i; j++) { // (+)
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I THINK I understand. My confusion wasn't about syntax or how to solve the problem, but what was actually causing the issue. As I now understand it, the row[] array was being pushed into the newArray[] array as a REFERENCE rather than a value, resulting in newArray[0], newArray[1], newArray[2] all pointing to the same location in memory, rather than holding references to unique row[] arrays.   Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of the array when pushing to `newArray`:

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row.slice());
  }
  return newArray;

}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
```

Answer (score 0):

Matrix `m` x `n` should be `m` rows and `n` cols.
So for `3, 2` you expect

```
[
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0],
  [0, 0],
]
```

Just declare `row` inside the first loop:

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  const newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;

}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```